# How to hault the javascript execution before calling a callback

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

Calling `alert` will hault the execution until the user presses "Ok". Is it possible to achieve the same pause-effect when using `sweetAlerts`?

My callback, which are refreshing the site, is now done immediately, hence the user doesn't get any time to read the sweetAlert. 
I want to give the user time to read the meassage, before the user presses "Ok" and the site will automatically refresh.

```
linkingOrUnlinkingDone = function (result) {
    alert('This will wait for the user to click the button');
    swal(result.text,
        hardcodedTextHelper.siteAutomaticallyRefresh(),
        result.type.toLowerCase(),
        window.location.reload(false)
    );
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [examples provided on SweetAlert github](https://github.com/t4t5/sweetalert), the syntax used to trigger a function **after** you click the button in the SweetAlert is as follows :

```
swal({
    title: "", // Your titles goes here
    text: "", // Your text goes here
    type: "", // Your text goes here
}, function(){
    // Your refresh function goes here
});
```

About the code you provided, you may be aware that when you pass **hardcodedTextHelper.siteAutomaticallyRefresh()** or **window.location.reload(false)** as a parameter, these functions are immediatly called : **hardcodedTextHelper.siteAutomaticallyRefresh** is a reference to a function, **hardcodedTextHelper.siteAutomaticallyRefresh()** is a call to that function.

Comment: Wrapping the callback in "function(){}" did the trick, thanks
--- My solution
    linkingOrUnlinkingDone = function (result) {
        swal({
            title: result.text,
            text: hardcodedTextHelper.siteAutomaticallyRefresh(),
            type: result.type.toLowerCase(),
        }, function () {
            window.location.reload(false);
        });
    },

Comment: @radbyx It is not a 'trick' : this callback is a feature of the plugin and is available only because the devs made it available.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. It was not meant as a trick as something magically happended, but more like it did the job and solved my problem.

Comment: @radbyx Fine, I thought it was worth mentioning, to make sure my answer was complete.